# StepRange description in Julia

Tags: julia

while working in julia programming, for creating an array instead of using `a=[1:1:20...]` i used `a=[1:1:20]` and it created an array saying `"1-element Array{StepRange{Int64,Int64},1}"`. 
What does this `"1-element Array{StepRange{Int64,Int64},1}"` mean? what `StepRange` means?

Comment: Note that you can use `1:20` instead of `1:1:20`. Also, most of the time, you don't need to convert it to an `Array`, just use `1:20` directly.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation of `StepRange` (type `?StepRange` in the Julia REPL to see this):

> ```
> StepRange{T, S} <: OrdinalRange{T, S}
> ```
>
> Ranges with elements of type T with spacing of type `S`. The step
>   between each element is constant, and the range is defined in terms
>   of a `start` and `stop` of type `T` and a `step` of type `S`. Neither `T` nor `S`
>   should be floating point types. The syntax `a:b:c` with `b > 1` and `a`,
>   `b`, and `c` all integers creates a `StepRange`.

So, for example

```
julia> typeof(1:1:20)
StepRange{Int64,Int64}
```

and

```
julia> [1:1:20]
1-element Array{StepRange{Int64,Int64},1}:
 1:1:20
```

thus constructs a `Vector` (1D `Array`) containing one `StepRange`. If you want to materialize the lazy `StepRange` I would recommend `collect(1:1:20)` instead of using splatting (`[1:1:20...]`).

You can access `start` / `step` / `stop` fields of a `StepRange` using:

```
julia> r = 1:1:20
julia> r.start
1

julia> r.stop
20

julia> r.step
1
```

Comment: Nice explanation!